# how can I strip the 00:00:00 from a date in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime, time

This might be a really simple question, but I'm using the code below to add 1 day to a date and then output the new date. I found this code online.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
  
# taking input as the date
Begindatestring = "2020-10-11"
  
# carry out conversion between string 
# to datetime object
Begindate = datetime.strptime(Begindatestring, "%Y-%m-%d")
  
# print begin date
print("Beginning date")
print(Begindate)
  
# calculating end date by adding 1 day
Enddate = Begindate + timedelta(days=1)
  
# printing end date
print("Ending date")
print(Enddate)
```

this code works but the output its gives me looks like this

```
Beginning date
2020-10-11 00:00:00
Ending date
2020-10-12 00:00:00
```

but for the rest of my code to run properly I need to get rid of the 00:00:00
so I need an output that looks like this

```
    Beginning date
    2020-10-11
    Ending date
    2020-10-12
```

It seems like there might be a simple solution but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
print(Begindate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Check https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime to learn more.

Comment: That worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Begindate = datetime.strptime(Begindatestring, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

Enddate = Enddate.date()
```